# How to implement calculated fields based on text input from another TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress

I have a very simple scenario and I need advise as to the best way to achieve this in ASP.NET MVC.

I have two textboxes, one editable and the other readonly.

The second textbox is meant to display a calculated figure based on the a calculation done on the server and the value entered in TextBox one.

I am using DevExpress's suite, but I guess the concept should be the same. Does anyone have sample code or can elaborate the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: If you're using .NET MVC, I think most people would suggest JavaScript + AJAX to do this. (Idk if "TextBox" or other DevExpress controls make sense here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   $("#textbox1_id).change(function(){
           var value1=$(this).val();
           $.ajax({
              url:'/abc/xyz',
              data:{myValue:value1},
              type:'GET',
              dataType:'json'
          })success(function(data){
            $("#textbox2").val(data.Value);
          });
     })    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for JQuery/Ajax.
You can set onChange event on your input box.
Through AJAX call to make a server side call to do the calculation and return the the results.
Then use JavaScript and JQuery to put the results in the non editable textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#InputID").onChange(function () {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/MyController/CalculatorAction/" + $("#InputID").val(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#ResultID").text(data);
        }
});
```

ON the controller side you can set up a post action

```
public virtual ActionResult GetEquipmentNumberByInitials(string id){
var result = 0;
// do calculation
return Json(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be fairly simple, you just need to access the text property of the textbox in which you are entering the value , and then applying calculation on the off focus event of the textbox use this value to calculate the other value and put it inside the text property of the textbox.

Use the below link for refrence
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T114245

Comment: I think that answer/link is specific to Web Forms

Comment: @mmcrae The MVC and WebForms DevExpress controls share a common base class; so the answer _should_ be easily appliable.

Comment: @UweKeim but is it possible to handle events like that in an MVC project? (I think not - everything goes through a controller - no PostBack with events tied to methods). Er OK I think not the events but the core work of the code could be similar